# Redirect Loop in symfony2 when forcing https

Tags: php, symfony, https, redirect-loop

In my Symfony2 app I have a firewall set up so that everything under the `/admin` route needs to be run through https, however when deployed I get a redirect loop. I've read the documentation on the Symfony2 site on firewalls, and setting up a login form. I've also read a few Stack Overflow articles and attempted their solutions, but nothing so far.

Below is my configuration, is there something I'm missing?

(As far as I know the server is running Apache, I've no direct access to server configuration from my hosting provider)

```
access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your own answer, it seems your website is behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy (since you need to check on the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` server variable, which is normally empty).

Your hosting provider may have put such a setup in place without your explicit knowledge. By default, Symfony ignores the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers, unless you [add the proxy to a whitelist](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html) in your `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
framework:
    trusted_proxies:  [127.0.0.1, ::1]
```

Where `127.0.0.1` and `::1` should be replaced by the actual proxy/proxies that your hosting provider uses (they should be able to tell you that).

Doing that should make it work without hacking the app.php file.

Comment: Cheers buddy! They mentioned Load Balancing when I contacted support. I imagine they didn't know about how Symfony works. Will implement the correct solution asap.

Comment: The same happened for me: using secure connection the "HTTPS" field didn't exist in the $_SERVER array and the "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" and also the "REMOTE_ADDR" fields both contained the client's IP, so I either couldn't set a trusted proxy IP. But I talked to my hosting service provider, maybe it could be fixed by his side and won't need that app.php hack. Thanks for the thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Update: Fixed the issue. It turns out some server variables were not set on the hosting provider.

For future reference, add the following under `app.php` in the web or public_html directory. Might be a dirty hack, but it fixed the issue for me.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
{ 
  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
  $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

Comment: Got me up an running locally.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the correct answer by @Oldskool , on SF > 3.3 you can use `env` variables to set `trusted_proxies` in SF4, as [the node were removed since that version](https://symfony.com/blog/fixing-the-trusted-proxies-configuration-for-symfony-3-3).

**In Symfony >3.2 <4**, the code is this:

```
# web/app.php

// BEFORE
// ...
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_FORWARDED, null);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// ...

// AFTER
// ...
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_FORWARDED, null);
Request::setTrustedProxies(['192.0.0.1', '10.0.0.0/8']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// ...
```

**If you are on SF4**, instead, you can use the `env` variables as the front controller (in `public/index.php`) reads them.

So, simply add the `env` variable `TRUSTED_PROXIES` putting in all your trusted proxies, separated by a comma ",":

```
TRUSTED_PROXIES = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/x,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/x,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/x
```

As a final reference, you can check the [issue on GitHub about the infinite loop caused by forcing the `https`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27603).

**ON HEROKU**

*As a simple reference as I had this problem with Heroku*

If you have troubles [forcing to `https`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/force_https.html) and your app is on Heroku:

You have to follow the [instructions provided by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony#trusting-the-load-balancer) (only for SF <= 3.2):

```
// web/app.php

Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_FORWARDED, null);
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST, null);
```

For Symfony > 3.2 ([instructions here for SF4](http://symfony.com/doc/4.0/deployment/proxies.html)):

```
// SF >= 4: public/index.php
...
$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Add this
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
...
```